# C++, getting i think the memory address instead of the string i want?

Tags: c++

I'm new to working on structures and came across this problem:

> In Germany, the house number is displayed after the street name; for example, Bahnhofstraße 1. Change the print_address function from this section so that it can print addresses in either format.
>
> ```cpp
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
> using namespace std;
>
> struct StreetAddress
> {
>    int house_number;
>    string street_name;
> };
>
> void print_address(StreetAddress address, bool number_first);
>
> int main()
> {
>     StreetAddress white_house;
>     white_house.house_number = 1600;
>     white_house.street_name = "Pennsylvania Avenue";
>     print_address(white_house, true);
>     cout << endl << "Expected: 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" << endl;
>     StreetAddress train_station;
>     train_station.house_number = 1;
>     train_station.street_name = "Bahnhofstraße";
>     print_address(train_station, false);
>     cout << endl << "Expected: Bahnhofstraße 1" << endl;
>     return 0;
> }
>
> void print_address(StreetAddress address, bool number_first)
> {
>    //code here
> }
> ```

Currently in the `code here` section, I have this:

```cpp
void print_address(StreetAddress address, bool number_first)
{
   StreetAddress s;
   if(number_first == true)
      cout << s.house_number << " " << s.street_name;
   else if (number_first == false)
      cout << s.street_name << " " << s.house_number;
}
```

I'm getting numbers instead of what I want. What's the problem here? I'm failing to see the issue.

Comment: Small sidenote: `if(number_first == true)` can be simplified to `if(numer_first)` and you can  simplify the `else if` to an `else` without any conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `print_address` function is declaring a local variable `StreetAddress s` and leaving it uninitialized, and then trying to print out the uninitialized "data" it contains.

I think what you intended was to print out the fields in the `address` argument, instead.

Comment: reference `address.house_number` and `address.street_name` in your `cout` lines, rather than `s.house_number` and `s.street_name`.  (In fact, get rid of the `StreetAddress s;` line entirely, as you don't need it and its presence is what is allowing your program to compile and do the wrong thing, rather than giving you a helpful compile-time error)

Comment: Ah, I had thought that I would have to somehow initialize the structure in the function itself. Is using the address reference due to the structure being initialized in the parameters?

Comment: Yes; you could alternatively do StreetAddress s = address; then you would have two identical StreetAddress objects (address and s) and you could print data from either of them.  There’s no benefit in this case to making a second copy, though.